# PhpStorm parameter hints in sass

Tags: sass, phpstorm

I have a scss file that I call in

```
@import ..mixins
```

but when I try to call in methods from the mixin that is defined like this

```
@mixin myFunction($param1, $param2){
style:$param1
style:$param2
}
```

Phpstorm just gives a hint like

```
myFunction()
```

without any parameter information. Has anyone found any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not yet supported in current versions on PhpStorm/WebStorm (stable 2016.3 and upcoming 2017.1).

Watch these tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10806
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24715

Answer (score 1):

I came here searching for this myself, and it isn't supported even in 2018.

It's not going to give you hinting apparently, but, for often used mixins you can create a live template (snippet) with variables.

In your case:

1) - Navigate to Settings: File>Settings>Editor>Live Templates. Then click the '+' to add a new 'snippet'.

`@mixin myFunction($$param1$, $$param2$);`

The extra `$` are for naming vars in Live Templates.

OR,

2) - Highlight the snippet of code to use for a new Live Template. Then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>(<kbd>CMD</kbd>)-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> and search "Save As Live Template". Double click or press enter to do '1)' much quicker if the code is already present.

That's a dirty workaround in the meantime.

What PHPStorm does support is: when you `@include myMix`, the hint will expand if you use the up, down arrows. Still not hinting, but almost.